# split function is duplicating values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split a string with `split()` and for some reason, it is giving me duplicate values this is driving me mad can someone please assist me

The string is a comma separated response from a database here is the echo
`echo $Title1 . ',' . $link. ','.$value. ','.'number'.','.'$' .',';`

Here is my code:

```
    function displayMatches(response2){
        var str = response2;
        var str_array = response2.split(',');
    }
```

This is the console log from `str_array`

```
0: "Butter cauliflower & paneer"
1: "https://link1.com"
2: "4"
3: "friends5"
4: "$"
5: "Butter cauliflower & paneer"
6: "https://link1.com"
7: "4"
8: "friends5"
9: "$"
10: "Butter cauliflower and coconut sambal"
11: "https://link2.com"
12: "3"
13: "friends5"
14: "$"
15: "Butter cauliflower and coconut sambal"
16: "https://link2.com"
17: "3"
18: "friends5"
19: "$"
```

Here is the value of response2

Butter cauliflower & paneer,https://link1.com,4,friends5,$,Butter cauliflower & paneer,https://link2.com,4,friends5,$,Butter cauliflower and coconut sambal,https://link3.com,3,friends5,$,Butter cauliflower and coconut sambal,https://link4.com,3,friends5,$,Creamy vegetarian pumpkin curry,https://link5.com,5,friends5,$,

```
Why is `split()` doing this?
```

Comment: please add the original string.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate values? Please [edit] your question to add example expected input and output.

Comment: If you print a string literal like `"Hello"` to the console using the same method, does it print duplicates?

Comment: @xdhmoore No I just tried it with another string it does not duplicate them

Comment: Without more info, it looks to me like your `response2` string has double of what you expect.

Comment: @xdhmoore it doesnt the second response is the log of response2 what more info can i give you to assist me?

Comment: What is the value of `response2` as it is passed into the function? I don't think what you have above is that, because it doesn't have any commas in it...

Comment: @xdhmoore I updated it for you

Comment: Great! Now, which part is the duplicate part?

Comment: see the print from str_array its printing https://link1.com twice it should be https://link2.com

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think it's possible for `console.log(response2.split(","))` to give that result based on the `response2` string you posted.

Comment: [`split()` is working fine](https://tio.run/##pZHBTsMwDEDv/QofEG2l0IltvTBxgTPfgLzU3bKlSeQ4hQrx7V23w9jgMombZfs9y/YOe4yaTZAH5xsaR0sCQp8Cz5C/JBFi0Jisaa3/mOJ7COiIWG1FQnyazaxx@8dK@04tVcuGXBNrdaduRec3oega0F57lwQidmu0V5LFSbL4n2T5V/LKhN0APW1IkA06CKkLe@NAJ@bhCq9PeH2J51nWJqfFeAeNicHi8IaitxQLphi8izQvvzKAHhmi8HTyc371k35HZhwui9XkMlLkKi@PfdNK0VuqrN8U5/6p8p1lv8YeH1uuxvEA). Most probably some code that you didn't post does something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one had also driven me mad.
Try using this **Inside the function**

```
let endArray = new Set([]);
var str_array = response2.split(',');
for(var i = 0;i < str_array.length - 1;i++){
  endArray.add(str_array[i]);
}
console.log(endArray)
```

Also, It would be easier if you would have added the string that you are splitting, This will help more viewers find better options and in less time.

If this didn't work get back to me on this answer as a comment

Comment: This printed unique values but it stopped at 11 but its better than what i have

Comment: This may have happened because the duplicate elements were removed, hence the length was shorterned, Also forgot to mention how to get values, You may want to read this, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sets-in-javascript/

Comment: It definitely doesn't I just updated it for you. The last responses are not getting printed they are being removed when I use split()

Comment: Thanks for the info. My mistake, just add a -1 after the str_array.length. The loop is iterating one extra time and hence, the last string is a ''.